# IP - Country based ad delivery

Tags: advertising, country-specific, ip-address

I am looking for an ad manager script/system (open source or paid) which can deliver different ads based on the IP - country of the visitors. Would be nice if you can name one if you know!

Comment: Given that the example(OpenX) you gave in response to @paulmorriss already *can* do geo-targeting, are there other requirements you're not bringing up? OpenX is more or less the standard as far as self-installed ad servers; is there a reason you're not just using it?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find an option to control ad delivery in OpenX panel. Is there such a feature there?

Comment: In their docs: [Geotargeting with OpenX](http://www.openx.org/support/geotargeting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do this using OpenX and GeoIP package installed. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google DFP it is the easiest way to do that

http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-dfp-tutorial/14099/

Watch the video and learn from it.. can't find a better resource

Answer (score 0):

[mySimpleAds](http://www.clippersoft.net/) has geo-targeting capabilities, but as the name implies it's not going to be a match for say, OpenX on features. It's worth a look if you don't have too much need for too much advanced stuff, though.